# Lyrical Contralto vs Dramatic Mezzo-soprano

Tags: voice, vocal-range, tone, pitch, opera

I'm a self-taught singer who would like to ask about lyrical contralto vs dramatic mezzo-soprano.

The range of my voice is from F3 - F5.
On the upper end, I can sing up to C5 quite comfortably.
(I've also hit A5, although it was *very* difficult for me.)

On the lower end, I can go all the way down to F3 (I can sing down to D3 or E3 with a little bit more difficulty).

I am not too sure where my mixed voice starts or ends; I believe I can sing with my chest voice up to D4-E4, and at C5, I use my head voice (maybe with a little bit of chest voice mixed in?)

And I was wondering what my fach would be. I apologize for the terrible recording: I recorded this after having a meal, and this recording may not accurately represent my range, but here's the sample:

https://voca.ro/1lHMcUgM4VWw

Thank you for reading!
I wish you a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues mixed in this question.

**Contralto vs. Mezzo Soprano**

The vocal ranges for lyric contralto and dramatic mezzo soprano are both F3 – F5. See for example

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contralto#Vocal_range
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzo-soprano#Dramatic

However, a contralto will be stronger in the lowest part of that range than will a mezzo soprano.

**Lyrical vs. Dramatic**

The distinction here is in vocal color and flexibility.

- A lyrical voice has a lightness to it and less power than a dramatic voice. ([SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contralto#Subtypes_and_roles_in_opera))
- A dramatic voice is darker and more powerful that a lyrical one. ([SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzo-soprano#Dramatic))

---

Based on the recording provided, my impression is that your voice is on the lighter side and is stronger/clearer in the upper part of your range compared to the lower. **My best sense is that** with additional training — *best done with a teacher who can properly evaluate and train your voice* — **you are a lyric mezzo soprano**.